# Wildcard error in iteration of a bash script - Shell

Tags: bash, shell, pdf, loops, wildcard

I have a bunch of pdf files that starts with a unique number. And each number represents a user. And now I am trying to concat all the pdf files from each user into an "AllInOne" file. But when i try to run my bash script, it doesn't recognize the wildcard in the pdftk command.

Every user will have a set of pdf files that are named as such:

```
1019-APP-CV-01.pdf  
1019-APP-SOI-01.pdf 
1019-APP-EC-01.pdf  
1019-APP-TOR-01.pdf     
1019-APP-TOR-02.pdf     
1019-ADM-LOR1-01.pdf 
1019-ADM-LOR2-01.pdf
```

I tried to run this **bash script**:

```
# Script for concat all pdf files of an array of applicants to one file.

#!/bin/sh
cd FILES
array=(1019 1041 1042 1043 1044 1049 1063 1070 1073 1074 1075 1077 1078 1079 1094 1105 1111 1115 1120 1122 1124 1137 1138 1141 1143 $

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
        pdftk $i-*.pdf cat output $i-AllInOne.pdf;
done
```

And I've got these messages for all users. **Error messages:**

```
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   1318-*.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   1319-*.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Is there something wrong with my wildcard in the bash script?

Comment: Putting #!/bin/sh on the third line of the file is utterly pointless.  The shebang is only used if it occurs in the first column of the first line.  (ie, the '#!' must be the first two bytes of the file.)

Comment: noted. But why does the script still works when i `$bash foobar.sh`??

Comment: Because you are specifying the interpreter and not asking the OS to determine the interpreter. Besides /bin/sh does not understand arrays, that's bash-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wildcard looks right to me; your error-message most likely just means that there are no files matching the pattern `1318-*.pdf` in the `FILES/` directory (or in the current directory, and `cd` failed because `FILES/` doesn't exist either; you can add `pwd` to check this). You see, in a command like this:

```
echo 1318-*.pdf
```

the pattern `1318-*.pdf` will only be replaced with filenames if there *are* any filenames for it to be replaced *with*. Otherwise it's left intact, and passed to the command as-is. (Well, that's the default behavior. You could set the `nullglob` option to have it just remove the pattern, or `failglob` to have it fail and not execute the command; but neither of those seems helpful here.)

It's possible to turn off filename expansion, by setting the `-f` option, so if you want you can add

```
set +f
```

just to make sure that filename expansion is turned on; but I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: After checking through, there isn't anything wrong with my wildcards. The problem lies in some of these pdf files are just not being able to `pdftk`. I've test it by trying to do a few of them manually. Thanks!!